# A Text Sections Classifier

Tags: nlp, training

I have a database of text files and I would like to classify each section(i.e references, abstract, etc...) in the text.

For example:

> Abstract Indexes: 100-300
>
> References Indexes: 9000-10000

Is there a package that is doing something like that?

Is there a recommended approach for doing so?

Comment: What kind of text format is underlying. Has it some level of structure (like LaTeX) or is it free text?

Comment: It's free text. It's basically a text extracted from documents(docx, pdf etc...) so I have the source files also.

Comment: Use a sequence model like a CRF or RNN to classify the sections collectively; cf. structured prediction and sequence prediction.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use the metadata of the individual sections for classification:

Examples:

1. Length -> Abstracts are usually short.
2. Existence of Figures -> Do not usually appear in abstract of references
3. Relative Abundance of quotations. The references should have a significant higher share of reference keys than the others.

You could then use the metadata as input for any supervised learning approach. For example a Neural Network or a (boosted) decision tree.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach might use [document vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07998) or [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) representing the text of each section (possibly chunking longer sections) with a simple classifier trained on those vectors to predict section. These can be found in [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) or [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda).

A harder to implement but likely more powerful technique would be to train a recurrent neural network on the text of each section (again likely breaking it into smaller chunks) so that the representation your model learns is learned specifically to predict Abstract/Indices/etc ...